# Writing C++ for STM32F0 LCD

Tags: c++, gpio, lcd, hd44780, stm32f0

I'm trying to learn embedded dev in C++ using CoIDE. I have a STM32F0 chip on a break out board.  i've done some LED tutorials etc.  I'm stuck on this code that is supposed to write some simple text strings to the LCD. The tutorial I'm following is at [eeherald tutorial](http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/sample_lcd_c_programs.html) i've adapted the code to my STM32F0 chip.
I think I'm close, but the LCD just stays in initialization mode with all the cells lit up. the screen never clears to write the text.  here's my code... any help to point me in the right direction would be APPRECIATED!

I "think" the problem may be in the initGPIO() for the data direction code, but I'm not sure... i've tried so many different things with no luck.

```
enter code here
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

#define EN  12 // EN Enable on PortB chip pin#53
#define RW  11 // RW Read Write on PortB chip pin#52
#define RS  10 // RS Register Select on PortB chip pin#51

void initGPIO(void);
void s_init(void);
void s_data(void);
void s_latch(void);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function Name : Init GPIO
// Description : pins ,port clock & mode initialization.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void initGPIO()
{
    // Define GPIO Structures
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    // Reset and clock control - Advanced high-performance bus - Enabling GPIO Port B and Port C
    __GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

    // Set Data Direction for Port C
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = RS | RW | EN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    //Set Data Direction for Port A
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function Name : s_init
// Description : Send Instruction Function (RS=0 & RW=0)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void s_init()
{
    GPIOC->BRR=RS;
    GPIOC->BRR=RW;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function Name : s_data
// Description : Send Data Select routine(RS=1 & RW=0)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void s_data()
{
    GPIOC->BSRR=RS;
    GPIOC->BRR=RW;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function Name : s_latch
// Description : Latch Data/Instruction on LCD Databus.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void s_latch()
{
    GPIOC->BSRR=EN;
    HAL_Delay(10);
    GPIOC->BRR=EN;
    HAL_Delay(10);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Function Name : main
* Description : Main program.
*******************************************************************************/
int main(void) //Main function
{

    initGPIO();

    int k=0;
    char a[]="WWW.EEHERALD.COM";
    char b[]="EMBEDDED SYSTEMS";

    GPIOC->BRR=RS; //Initialize RS=0 for selecting instruction Send
    GPIOC->BRR=RW; // Select RW=0 to write Instruction/data on LCD
    GPIOC->BSRR=EN; // EN=1 for unlatch. (used at initial condition)

    HAL_Delay(10);

    s_init(); //Call Instruction Select routine
    GPIOB->ODR=0x0001; // Clear Display, Cursor to Home
    s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction
    GPIOB->ODR=0x0038; // Display Function (2 rows for 8-bit data; small)
    s_latch(); //Latch this above instruction 4 times
    s_latch();
    s_latch();
    s_latch();
    GPIOB->ODR=0x000E; // Display and Cursor on, Cursor Blink off
    s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction
    GPIOB->ODR=0x0010; // Cursor shift left
    s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction
    GPIOB->ODR=0x0006; // Cursor Increment, Shift off
    s_data(); //Change the input type to Data.(before it was instruction input)
    s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction

    for(k=0;a[k];k++)
    {
        GPIOB->ODR=a[k]; //It will send a[0]='P' as = '0x0050' on Port B.
        s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction only once. Or it will clone each character twice if you latch twice.
    }
    GPIOC->BRR=RS; //Initialize RS=0 for selecting instruction Send
    GPIOC->BRR=RW; // Select RW=0 to write Instruction/data on LCD
    GPIOC->BSRR=EN; // EN=1 for unlatch. (used at initial condition)


    GPIOB->ODR=0x00C0; // Move cursor to beginning of second row
    s_latch(); //Latch the above instruction
    s_data(); //Change the input type to Data.(before it was instruction input)
    for(k=0;b[k];k++)
    {
        GPIOB->ODR=b[k]; //It will send b[0]='E' as = '0x0044' on Port B.
        s_latch();//Latch the above instruction only once. Or it will clone each character twice if you latch twice.
    }
    s_init();
}
```

Comment: one problem I see, that the initialization is not so good, for example the command 0x0001 to clear display take long time and you have no wait.

Comment: if you will not wait, then other commands during procesing will be ignored, look at datasheet: https://www.sos.sk/productdata/63/27/5/63275/bc1602Aver01.pdf on page 25 for correct initialization with right delays.